# Null pointer error reading text file and storing it in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, filereader

I've written a main method for it also, but I can't tell the source of the error. This is the code I'm using:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 public class WordList{
  private ArrayList<String> words;

 public WordList(String filename){
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public ArrayList<String> openFile(String filename) throws IOException{
FileReader fr= new FileReader(filename);
//create a Filereader object
BufferedReader textReader= new BufferedReader(fr);
//create a BR object
String line = textReader.readLine();
while (textReader.readLine() != null){
  words.add(line);
  textReader.readLine();
}
textReader.close();
return words;
}
Random r= new Random();
public String getRandomWord(){
String x= new String();
int y=r.nextInt(words.size());
x= words.get(y);
return x;

 }
}
```

This is the main method I used for testing my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 public class Test{
  public void main(String args[])throws IOException{
 String path= "C:/Users/Cyril/Desktop/COMP 202/Assignment 4/Text files/Majors.txt" ;

 try {
WordList list = new WordList(path);
ArrayList<String> majors = new ArrayList<String>();
majors = list.openFile(path);
System.out.println(majors);
}

catch (IOException e){
  System.out.println( e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

I am getting a null pointer error. I can't find the source of it.
The question I had was:

Write a class WordList with a private arraylist that reads a textfile and stores every line as an entry in the arraylist.
I've added the random method to generate random words from the arraylist.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: The instance should use the interface, e.g. List<String> not ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private ArrayList<String> words;

public WordList(String filename){
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

In this part of your code , the constructor is creating another array list and the one in your class(instance variable ) is not linked to it.

please change your code to :

```
private ArrayList<String> words;

public WordList(String filename){
this.words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

It should then work :)

Answer (score 3):

You've declared a local variable which shadows the instance member

```
public WordList(String filename){
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

change to

```
public WordList(String filename){
    words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

[But also see Kugathasan's answer...which they just deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359879/438154)

This snippet

```
String line = textReader.readLine();
while (textReader.readLine() != null){
    words.add(line);
    textReader.readLine();
}
```

You are reading 3 lines from the input stream. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a local variable with same name as instance variable in the constructor instead of assigning the instance variable.
So Change the declaration to assignment in your constructor ,like this.

```
public WordList(String filename){
   words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public WordList(String filename) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

to

```
  public WordList(String filename) {
     words = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Because you have shadowed your instance member `words` in the constructor, `words` is not initialized and defaults to `null` and `null.Something` is a `NullPointerException`